# Is it possible to post message to a conversation on Skype using directline

Tags: botframework

We have a scenario , wherein we are trying to post messages to users (which have conversations with Bot opened on Skype channels ) through directline api.
We are unable to achieve this.

But we are able to broadcast messages from a conversation on Webchat to another conversation on webchat .
Similarly from one conversation in Skype to another conversation on Skype.

Is it possible to broadcast a message from directline to a conversation on Skype ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a message to your bot, requesting this. Your bot can choose the correct channel to answer.